# Why does my connection string not work?

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5, connection-string

I want to upload my website. I uploaded my database's backup file and the connection string that the host give me is:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=sama;Password=****;
```

and I set the connection string in the `web.config` file like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyDBContext"  
        connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;User Id=sama;Password=****;Initial Catalog=sama;" 
        providerName="sqloledb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but my website doesn't work!

I use Entity Framework code-first model in my project.

Where is my problem??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any feedback? Any error message?

Comment: @AlexBarroso:yes,the error page that i set in web.config for customErrors is showed!

Comment: Disable the customErrors page so you can see the error detail

Comment: @AlexBarroso:thanks i do,i understand where is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="MyDBContext" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=sama;User Id=sama;Password=****;"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```